# HtmlPurifierBundle How to configure URI.SafeIframeRegexp in config.yml Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, htmlpurifier

How to configure HTML.SafeIframe and URI.SafeIframeRegexp in Symfony2 config.yml?

I tried:

```
exercise_html_purifier:
 default:
     Cache.SerializerPath: '% kernel.cache_dir% / htmlpurifier'
 custom:
     Cache.SerializerPath: '% kernel.cache_dir% / htmlpurifier'
     Core.Encoding: 'utf-8'
     URI.AllowedSchemes: {http: true}
     HTML.SafeIframe: true
     URI.SafeIframeRegexp: '% ^ (https:) // (www \ .youtube (- nocookie) \ com / embed / | player \ .vimeo \ .com / video /)%'
```

But it gives me an error on URI.SafeIframeRegexp:

ParameterNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent parameter "^ (https:) // (www \ .youtube (- nocookie) \ com / embed / | player \ .vimeo \ .com / video /?).? ".

I try this:

```
URI.SafeIframeRegexp: "/^(https?:)?//(www.youtube(?:-nocookie)?.com/embed/|player.vimeo.com/video/)/"
```

and this:

```
URI.SafeIframeRegexp: "^(https?:)?//(www.youtube(?:-nocookie)?.com/embed/|player.vimeo.com/video/)"
```

and this:

```
URI.SafeIframeRegexp: "#^(https?:)?//(www\.youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/embed/|player\.vimeo\.com/video/)#"
```

No more error but is still efcaped. In my text I have:

```
<iframe width = "560" height = "315" src = "// www.youtube.com/embed/jAHlQ77lm10" frameborder = "0" allowfullscreen> </ iframe>
```

edit 2: I had :

```
HTML.SafeObject: true
Output.FlashCompat: true
```

but still does not work.

edit 3: 
I tried HTML.Allowed: iframe but even that does not work, for against my other tags were not working.

My last config:

```
# HTMLPurifier
exercise_html_purifier:
default:
    Cache.SerializerPath: '%kernel.cache_dir%/htmlpurifier'
custom:
    Cache.SerializerPath: '%kernel.cache_dir%/htmlpurifier'
    Core.Encoding: 'utf-8'
    URI.AllowedSchemes: { http: true }
    HTML.SafeObject: true
    Output.FlashCompat: true
    HTML.SafeIframe: true
    URI.SafeIframeRegexp: "#^(https?:)?//(www\.youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/embed/|player\.vimeo\.com/video/)#"
```

(I also posted this problem here: https://github.com/Exercise/HTMLPurifierBundle/issues/20)

While I want the video to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. My mistake was to put the code for the iframe:

```
<iframe width = "560" height = "315" src = "// www.youtube.com/embed/jAHlQ77lm10" frameborder = "0" allowfullscreen> </ iframe>
```

in my textarea so that I had to put it in VIEWCODE of tinymce.
Very stupid mistake.